# Magento Multi-store 404 on chrome only

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore

I have a strange issue on magento multi-store setup. This is how our stores are setup.

[image: Magento stores]

Each stores have separate folders with their own .htaccess and index.php files.

The issue is, when my PO and Client access some category pages in chrome, they get 404 but everything is fine in all other browsers.

I created [404 logger](https://github.com/dbashyal/Technooze_T404/blob/master/app/code/community/Technooze/T404/Model/Observer.php) to capture request data and found out (seems), it's looking page in different store.
e.g. instead of looking page at: 
`url.com.au/home-solutions/category-page` (au/home-solutions store view) it's looking in `url.com/category-page` (global store view) and sometimes in `url.com.au/business-solutions/category-page` (au/business-solutions store view)

As that category is assigned to 'home-solutions' (au/nz), it will be 404 for other stores.

Currently, there is no actual domain, we are testing with IP address and "Australia Website" only. Not sure if this issue will be resolved once we go live with actual domain.

It would be appreciated to get some views from some Magento top minds.

**Magento ver. 1.7.0.2**

**UPDATE**

Found how to replicate issue myself on my machine. If I access `url.com.au/home-solutions/category-page?___store=au_business` then every category page from au_home store returns 404 on that browser.

Comment: after adding store pare return 404 error, can i get tutorial for adding store in magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing store param from url and reloading the site.

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('store');
$url = trim(str_replace("___store={$storeParam}", '', $url), '?');
$response->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

Check the observer I created to manage these 404 pages in multi-store magento installation.

- https://github.com/dbashyal/Technooze_T404/blob/master/app/code/community/Technooze/T404/Model/Observer.php